# Issue with connecting Microsoft Bot (using .NET) to reddis database

Tags: .net, redis, botframework

I am trying to integrate Reddis with my ChatBot written using Microsoft SDK for .NET
The problem is when I am using the call to RegisterBotDependencies() method for conversation storage the Bot springs up with the issue "Sorry my bot code is having an issue".
Also from the documentation it is unclear where to write what?
where is the data being stored?
How to access it?
I have also opened a New Issue in :
https://github.com/ankitbko/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.RedisStore/issues/4
but no one has answered.

Comment: Maybe no one has answered because you did not add any details about where and how you tried to implement that. Add details about your code please. And have a look to the user's blog post about the implementation : https://ankitbko.github.io/2016/10/Microsoft-Bot-Framework-Use-Redis-to-store-conversation-state/

Comment: the code is given on the link..I just used that.
also the sample code given in the repo also doesn't run